# How to make an array of CSS classes

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I make an array of CSS classes, not the CSS class names? I need the "." and everything.

I need users to be able to click on certain buttons, and add the classes the button belongs to into an array.

I used this before:

```
var myPicks[];
$('.button').click( function() {
    var hello = " " + $(this).attr('class').split(' ')[0];
    myPicks.push(hello);
}
```

But that seems to add the name of the classes, not the classes themselves. It's possible I'm wrong and there's something wrong with another part of my JQuery code.

Comment: Can you please explain the difference between "class" and "class name" in this context?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why do you need the classes for? If you just want to apply the classes to an element later, you can store the class and do `.addClass(myPicks[i])`.

Comment: @cdhowie — I think "CSS class" means either "rule-set" or "selector" and "CSS class name" means "HTML class".

Comment: @cdhowie Sorry, I didn't explain it well. A class-name would be "myClass" and the class would be ".myClass"

Comment: @ThierryJ. I want to use .filter(), which seems to require the actual class.

Comment: @Stan I think the terms you are going for are "class" and "selector."

Comment: @cdhowie Thanks for the correction! Haven't gotten the jargon down yet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
var myPicks = [];
$('.button').click( function() {
    Array.prototype.push.apply(myPicks, $.map($(this).attr('class').split(' '), function(value, idx){
        return '.' + value
    }))

    console.log('myPicks', myPicks)
});
```

if you want only unique classes

```
var myPicks = [];
$('.button').click( function() {

    $.each($(this).attr('class').split(' '), function(idx, value){
        var selector = '.' + value;
        if($.inArray(selector, myPicks) == -1){
            myPicks.push(selector)
        }
    })

    console.log('myPicks', myPicks)
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/D3VPt/)

Answer (score 0):

I will not recommend save the name of the class with the dot included into that array(), It will be useless if you need it later for something else.
(Or your goint to need to split it again)

Instead, I suggest to save it like you have now and then **and only when you needed**, *add the dot to that value*

like:

```
var myPicks = new Array(); 
myPicks[0] = "something";

// original value:
var newValue = myPicks[0]; // newValue == 'something'
//used as ID:
var newValue = '#' + myPicks[0]; // newValue == '#something'
// used as a class:
var newValue = '.' + myPicks[0]; // newValue == '.something'
```

BUT, of course if you need that way... just replace the `PUSH` function and add the dot to it:

```
var newHello = '.' + hello;
myPicks.push(newHello);
```

Comment: `new` is a JavaScript keyword, don't use it as a variable name.

Comment: @cdhowie absolutely right... my mistake. Thanks for pointing that out.